# Disable Button till password/access code entered (PHP)

Tags: php, html

**Edit: Apologies for the bad wording, a better version is below:**
When the user first visits the site they see i.stack.imgur.com/7zbyv.png. They then have to enter a set password (PHP variable) and click submit. If it is correct i.stack.imgur.com/E78wK.png will show. If not, nothing will happen.

---

I am working on a script over at my development site. I am looking to replace the big green button with a text box and a submit button. The user must enter the correct password into the box and click the submit button before the green button is displayed. I cannot find a guide on how to do this anywhere. Can anyone help me? I have put the relevant code and screenshots below:

Green Button:

[image]

```
<?php
    if(($xx != null) || $log != null)
    {
    echo "<a rel=\"tooltip\" title=\"Login via Instagram using your username\" class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"$loginUrl\">Login with Instagram</a>";
    } 
?>
```

Login Form and Button

[image]

```
<form>
        <br />
        <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Enter Code...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's very simple -- you output both the form and the button when the user is not logged in. You use CSS to hide the form, and only display the button. Then user jQuery `click()` (or simple javascript) handler to toggle the button with the form.

Here's a demonstartion of said technique with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/uHzfp/

Comment: Sorry, that was not what I meant. What I means is that when the user first visits the site they see http://i.stack.imgur.com/7zbyv.png. They then have to enter a set password (PHP variable) and click submit. If it is correct http://i.stack.imgur.com/E78wK.png will show. If not, nothing will happen

Comment: so they simply submit the form with the password, and PHP checks that. If it's correct it shows the second step; if not, the first. I don't see what the question is then

Comment: My question was what is the PHP to check the password?

Comment: please revise form basics for PHP here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help. I always prefer it when people help me to do it myself rather than just doing it for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if(($xx != null) || $log != null)
    {
    echo "<a id="login_button" rel=\"tooltip\" title=\"Login via Instagram using your username\" class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"$loginUrl\" >Login with Instagram</a>";
    } 
?>

<form id="myform" style="display:none;">
        <br />
        <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Enter Code...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
</form>

<script>
$("#login_button").click(function () {
$(this).css("display","none");
$('#myform').css("display","");
});
</script>
```

Comment: My deepest apologies for the poor wording, I have edited my post. Thanks for taking the time to answer. What I means is that when the user first visits the site they see i.stack.imgur.com/7zbyv.png. They then have to enter a set password (PHP variable) and click submit. If it is correct i.stack.imgur.com/E78wK.png will show. If not, nothing will happen